# Efficiently testing if one list is a permutation of another

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, permutation

I was reading http://comicjk.com/comic.php/906 where the problem of checking if one list is a permutation of another is presented and two solutions are proposed.

The 'c brain' solution "you know the lists will always contain four numbers of fewer, and each number will be less than 256, so we can byte-pack all the permutations into 32-bit ints and..."

The 'python brain' solution is to sort both and then compare them, this seems more obvious, but I am interested in a more efficient (and low level) solution.

### My initial approach was:

```
int permutations(int a[4], int b[4]){
  int A = a[0] | a[1]*1<<8 | a[2]*1<<16 | a[3]*1<<24;
  int B = b[0] | b[1]*1<<8 | b[2]*1<<16 | b[3]*1<<24;

  unsigned int c=0, i=0;

  for( i=0xFF; i>0; i<<=8 ){
      if( 
        A&i == B&0xFF ||
        A&i == B&0xFF00 ||
        A&i == B&0xFF0000 ||
        A&i == B&0xFF000000
      ) c |= i;
  }

  if( c == 0xFFFFFFFF )
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

But this cant work unless I can find an easy way to position both A&i and B*0xxxxxxxxx both at the same byte (removing any trailing 0s after the byte we are looking at).
So something like

```
(a&i>>al)>>ar == b(&j>>bl)>>br
```

where al+ar == bl+br == 4 and are used to determine which byte we are examining.

### Another approach

Someone in the comments box said "In C, why not simply dynamically allocate a section of memory of appropriate size and treat it as a single number?
True it'd be a bit slower than using an int but it'd also not be restricted to contain four or fewer elements or maximum number of 256, and still be faster than sorting (whether in C or Python) ..."

If we could have an array which has a length in bits greater than our highest number, then we could set the appropriate bits and compare the arrays, but this gives more comparisons as we then have  comparisons unless we can treat this as one large number efficiently in c.

In x86 (which I have just started learning) we have the SBC instruction so we could subtract each part and if the results are all zero (which we could test with a JNE/JNZ) they are equal.

As far as I can tell we would still have to do / SBCs and jumps

### Actual question

I would like to know how

1. byte packing
2. treating the whole list as one large number

can be used to check if a list is a permutation of another (assuming the lists are no longer than 4 items and each item is < 256)

Comment: "(assuming the lists are no longer than 4 items and each item is < 256)" With these assumptions, most solutions are constant time. The O notation is about asymptotic behavior, not about telling you how many comparisons are necessary to sort 4 elements. Anyway, if you relax the conditions just a little, you can still use linear time bucket-sort to sort the lists before comparing them.

Comment: The following will work: Make a hash table mapping (element -> count(element)) for the first list (by iterating it and inserting/incrementing). Then iterate the second list, decrementing the counts. If you were unable to decrement the count for a key (does not exist in hash or is zero), or the lists have different length, they are not permutations; otherwise, they are. This has O(1) time complexity, assuming the hash function worked well.

Comment: @Pascal Thanks for the comment. The O notation shouldn't have still been in there, somehow it got left behind after a few edits (I don't write my questions in a single pass). With a merge sort over 4 items we are only looking at about 5 comparisons. With the constraints in place this question does seem silly, its more the concept rather than the actual solution I am interested in.

Comment: @cjh and interesting ideas have already come of your question, viz Ambroz Biwjak's comment (more general than my own suggestion) and hobbs's answer, so it definitely wasn't silly.

Comment: Oops, I meant O(n) time complexity not O(1), obviously.

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak Would it not still be O(n) as you still must build the mapping and compare each item to it? EDIT: I guess I should really learn to click the 'show n comments' before typing my reply

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak I quite like the solution of building the count map (even better if you were to count something being in the second lest as negative in the map) so you can then answer 'how different are they'.

Comment: @cjh, Yes, I just noticed my mistake. Of course you won't get anything better than O(n) in the worst case. I'm also not sure if there's an asymptotically faster way to probabilistically detect certain cases of non-permutations. For instance, if you choose to examine some specific positions in both lists, whatever you see, the non-examined part would likely still allow the lists to be permutations.

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak Best case all you need to find is one item in either list that is not in the other, this doesn't help if they are actually permutations of course, afaik worst case will always be O(n) due to the nature of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a hash that is not affected by permutations.  Addition was offered as one method.  I was thinking of a method that would be compatible with a [bloom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter%28%28%28a%29) filter, so you could do more things with it.

A bloom filter would work with lists of arbitrary lengths and numbers of arbitrary size.  It could be used to see if a list had the same permutations as a group of lists.  It can be used to see if an element might exist in a list.

A bloom filter is basically an array of bits.  You just 'or' the bits of the elements making up your list together to produce the bloom filter.  Any list with the same elements in any order will have the same bits set.  For small lists you can get away with using integer sized numbers for the bit arrays:

```
unsigned char b = a1|a2|a3|a4; // where a1..n are items (8 bit numbers)
```

if you had item a1 and a list with bloom b and wanted to know if a1 was in the list:

```
fPossibleMatch = ((a1&b) == a1);
```

if you had two lists of arbitrary lengths with blooms b1, b2 and wanted to know if all items of b1 might exists in b2:

```
fPossibleMatch = ((b1&b2) == b1);
```

If you wanted to know if list b1 and b2 with the same # of elements were permutations of each other.

```
fPossibleMatch = (b1==b2);
```

To cut down on false positives, widen the bloom filter.  If we used a 64 bit bloom, we could use this arbitrarily chosen algorithm to spread bits out:

```
unsigned long long b = (a1<<(a1&0x1F)) | (a2<<(a2&0x1F)) | (a3<<(a3&0x1F)) | a4<<(a4&0x1F);
```

I have a feeling that my algorithm to widen the bloom is not any good.  It might just set all the bits to mush.  Someone else might know of a better way.  I think you get the idea though.

I think this is better:

```
#define MUNGE(a) ((a)<<(((a)&7)<<3))
unsigned long long b = MUNGE(a1)|MUNGE(a2)|MUNGE(a3)|MUNGE(a4)
```

I'm not good at creating hashes.

You still have to double check any lists that have matching bloom filters.  The number of false positives increases with increasing list length and element size.  False positives decrease with increasing bloom size.

Comment: Even though this will only approximate it, its still the closest,  I remember reading about bloom filters but couldnt think of the name. Thanks for mentioning how to expand the bloom space as I believe this answers both my queries.

Comment: expanding the bloom space is definitely important.  I am sure there are some better algorithms than I cam up with.  Maybe someone can comment with a better one.

Answer (score 2):

Optimization assuming that the result is probably "no": calculate the sum (or the xor, or some other inexpensive, associative, commutative operator) of each list. If the sums differ, the answer is no without further testing. If the sums are the same, then perform a more expensive test to get a definitive answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought of this but didn't quite like it. I was thinking of |ing the numbers together and doing a quick equality test. It isn't what the comic was alluding to either way as we would only need 8 bits rather than 32 for the initial comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hashtable and iterate through each list. This will give a solution that requires O(n) time and O(n) memory.